Wordpress multisite with subdomains behind nginx reverse proxy using subdirectories
I'm trying to create a working configuration for a wordpress multisite using subdomains behind a nginx reverse proxy using subdirectories.
There a two domains hosted on Plesk server A running nginx (domain.de and domain.at). The wordpress multisite is hosted on a different Plesk server B running apache (wpmulti.de with two sudomains sub1.wpmulti.de and sub2.wpmulti.de). Both domains on Plesk server A should proxy the subdirectory "blog" to their corresponding wordpress subdomain i.e. domain.de/blog -> sub1.wpmulti.de and domain.at/blog -> sub2.wpmulti.de.
For simplicity i will only mention domain.de, wpmulti.de and sub1.wpmulti.de from now on. The config for domain.at and sub2.wpmulti.de should work exactly the same after adjusting the domain names.
I've added the following location rule to the nginx config of domain.de:
location = /blog/ {
    rewrite ^ /blog permanent;
}

location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter 'sub1.wpmulti.de' '$host';
    sub_filter_once off;

    proxy_pass https://sub1.wpmulti.de;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}

I've also added the following lines to the wp-config.php of wpmulti.de:
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

if (isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) {  
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'];
}

The .htaccess file of wpmulti.de looks like this:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I've also changed siteurl and home to domain.de/blog for sub1.wpmulti.de. Furthermore permalinks are set to https://domain.de/blog/%postname%.
Still there is a major problem with this setup that I can't seem to resolve. There are no trailing slashes and I can only use a static homepage. When using the wordpress default, latest posts, the homepage is stuck in a redirect loop (with and without trailing slash).
So far I've tried a few different things:

Remove the location = /blog/ location rule and adding trailing slashes to siteurl, home and permalinks. This does work when using latest posts but when using a static homepage domain.de/blog/ ends in a redirect loop
Remove the location = /blog/ location rule, add a trailing slash to location ^~ /blog and proxy_pass, change the sub filter to sub_filter 'sub1.wpmulti.de' '$host/blog';. This works with both the latest posts and static homepage. However the backend is not really usable in this state. A lot of functions, including the search bars as an example, are missing the "blog" slug and redirect to domain.de/wp-admin (instead of domain.de/blog/wp-admin).
Not using a sub_filter but instead changing the header and/or $_SERVER variable. As soon as i try to change the HTTP_HOST either by using proxy_set_header Host domain.de; or by setting it in wp-config.php with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']; the entire page just redirects to the network root page wpmulti.de. I've also tried many combinations with trailing slashes, with the blog subdirectory, and changing other variables as well (such as $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])

I'm trying random things at this point. This should be possible but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.
